# Implement place picker dialog in flutter application

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am making an android application using flutter. I want to know how can I implement google place picker dialog in Flutter as we implement in the android studio. I am new to flutter so don't have an idea how to do this. Someone, please help us with code how can I implement this functionality in Flutter.

**THANKS**

https://github.com/humazed/google_map_location_picker

please follow this link. if you are new in Flutter development.

Comment: Try this : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_places_picker

Comment: @DhirajSharma Thanks, I have been through it but there is not much given except configuration in android and ios.Could you tell what to do after adding Api key in manifest.xml file.

Comment: https://github.com/derTuca/flutter_google_places_picker/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: Don't use it. PlacePicker is deprecated and it will be removed soon. Read here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [`google_map_location_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_location_picker) plugin for since it uses the official Google Maps plugin for Flutter https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: This package is not under maintenance in 2024 and is not Dart 3 compatible. Any package alternatives would be nice.